# Nested findall() with ‘case’ equivalent to include statement

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I am very new to APIs (a week in) and I’m stuck with a challenge.

I have tables in Postgres and have created models for each. There is a link from one to another (in some circumstances). If the link doesn’t exist then I want to use a default value, held in a different table.

Example:

```
Table - items
- id (int)
- name (text)
- startDateTime (date)
- endDateTime (date)

Table - itemTypes
- id (int)
- name (text)
- isDefault (boolean)

Table - itemTypesLinkItems
- id (int)
- itemsId (int)
- itemTypesId (int)
- fromDateTime (date)
- toDateTime (date)
```

At any given date, there will be a list of items that display. Some of those might be linked to itemTypes via the itemTypesLinkItems table, and so I can show the itemTypes.Name. For the remainder, I’d like to show the itemTypes.Name value where the isDefault = true.

I’ve searched all over, tried to do it with SQL views, but no luck. I’m hoping this is something that can be done within the JavaScript of the API.

```
router.get(‘/:date’, (req, res) =>
db.items.findAll()({
  include: [
    {
    model: db.itemtypelinkitem,
    required: false,
    include: [
      {
      model: db.itemtypes 
      }
    ]
    where: {
      startDateTime: {[Op.lte]: req.params.date},
      endDateTime: {[Op.gte]: req.params.date}
    }
    }
  ]
```

I just don’t know where to go from here. If I exclude the ‘required’ then only those items with a link are returned. If I include it, then they all show and if there is a link it returns the details, otherwise just returns []. In the event that it returns a [], I’d like to replace that with the values from the default itemTypes.

Answer (score 0):

I hope understood your question well.

You made **many to many** Relation between (items, itemTypes) and want to get a default 
itemType when getting all items.
so I think this problem not related to Sequlize.
You have to insert default 'itemType' while inserting a new record into 'items' table.